# How much play time to complete Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

Simple question: about how many hours of gameplay are required to complete Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess?  I know that it depends upon skill and how thoroughly one explores the game, but can I please have a ballpark estimate of how long I should expect to take to finish the game?

Comment: @kotekzot I can see how that answer could be used in answering this one but there's no way it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Studoku The other option is to close (and eventually delete) it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/26160028) contains the completion times for various people,  in response to someone asking the same question you did. The hours for completion ranged from 40-65. The total completion varies - some are for 100%, some for much less.

[Another thread asking the same question](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/928519-the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/50412351?page=1) had an average completion of around 50 hours, although some people took as little as 25 hours (for second playthrough), and one person took 120 hours for their first play through and 242 for their second (I think there numbers might be off though... for obvious reasons). A [few](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/forums/gamecube-and-wii-zelda/87311-how-long-does-it-take-you-to-beat-twilight-princess-on-the-gamecube-wii.html) [other](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/920769-the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/41217164) [threads](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1140188) have people clocking in around 40-50 hours as well, with a few people going as low as 20 hours for the first playthrough. The [last thread](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1140188) also has a poll, with the majority taking 40+ hours.

A [few](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080502120944AADxpsF) [other](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_long_is_Twilight_Princess_on_the_first_playthrough) [Q&A](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090718074303AAbZ1yj) [sites](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_long_does_it_take_to_beat_zelda_twilight_princess) have times ranging from 40-60 hours as well. This [Sorean person](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23637/how-much-play-time-to-complete-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/23641#23641) took about 20 hours, although not sure if I trust that Stack Exchange site... some pretty shifty folk on there.

[IGN's review](http://wii.ign.com/articles/746/746691p3.html) states:

> It'll keep you busy for at least 50
>   hours and you could spend double that
>   in Nintendo's new Hyrule. So much to
>   do and see that you'll be busy for
>   weeks, if not months.

[In response to a question posed by Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/212449/twilight-princess-dungeon-and-length-details), Nintendo reps stated the game has 70 hours of gameplay.

[Howlongtobeat.com](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamebreakdown.php?gamename=The%20Legend%20of%20Zelda:%20Twilight%20Princess) has the average for the main quest at 34 hours, and an average of 57 hours to achieve 100%. The average for all players was 48 hours.

As you can see, on average it takes people anywhere from 40-60 hours for their first play through; although some people completed it in half that time, and others over double. In other words, it depends on a combination of your skill level and how much exploration you do.

Comment: The ratio of # references to question simplicity is approaching infinity here. +1

Comment: I wonder if there's a website that documents playtime for all RPG games.

Answer (score 5):

It took me about 65 hours. I looked for every golden bug, every heart container, and every item **as the game progressed**. I did *not* search for every Po. It took me several hours to beat the abominable snowman's wife, Yeta, snow-boarding. She's a dirty, dirty cheater.

Comment: Indeed. Yeta was the single thing that made me curse while playing this game. The rest of the game was full of "how cool is that?" moments.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at about 20-25 hours if you do everything and don't die a lot (a few deaths is to be expected).

*First hand experience so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Sounds a bit too low for doing everything. I did it all, didn't die much, and clocked around 55 hours.

Answer (score 1):

-Edit-

Whoops i didnt read the title good enough >.< i had OOT in my head when seeing the playtimes.

But TP took me about 26/28 hours

Answer (score 0):

I've almost finished the story, and I'm at 40 hours. I have all the golden bugs, all the hidden skills, not all the heart containers (5 PoH per HC, AND there are fewer dungeons in this game than OoT or LttP? They're insane).

Answer (score 0):

I found this new website today that collects people's play time and average it: [How long till I beat Zelda Twilight Princess.](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamebreakdown.php?gameid=852)